# Intel Fortran OpenMP compiler options

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, openmp, intel

I am running into some issues as the same code yields different results depending on whether I compile it using Visual studio or directly through the command line.

If I compile through Visual Studio these is the default options, to which I add `/Qopenmp` and a stacksize of 9999999 on project properties:

```
/nologo /debug:full /Od /Qopenmp /module:"Debug\\" /object:"Debug\\" 
/Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /traceback /check:bounds /check:stack /libs:dll 
threads /dbglibs /c
```

If I compile directly through command line I use:

```
ifort /openmp /F999999999 Main.f90
```

The first option paralellizes but takes 57 hours to run. The second option takes 6 hours. The issue is that the results are different between both and I have no clue why.

Comment: Which code taks that much to run?

Comment: I am completely clueless on why the difference between the two compilation methods (via visual studio interface vs via command line)

Comment: Me too. That's why we need some code.

Comment: One of the issues is that you also use different compiler options. `/check:bounds` will do run-time checks that slow down the code. If you want to compare both methods, use the same options for a start.

Comment: Okay. Now I am compiling with this. It is still way slower. Not sure if results are different as of now.

/nologo /O2 /Qopenmp /module:"Release\\" /object:"Release\\" /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /libs:dll /threads /c